# How to discard Oracle UTF-8 characters when writing to a file with utl_file.put_line

Tags: oracle, utf-8

I am using the following code to write to a file in Oracle PL/SQL.

```
l_file := utl_file.fopen('HR_OUT', 'TRUMEDAID.txt', 'w');
utl_file.put_line
(
   l_file,
   utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2
   (
      utl_raw.convert
      (
         utl_raw.cast_to_raw(rec_text),
         'AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1',   -- To character set.
         'AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8'        -- From Character set.
      )
   )
);
```

However this does not discard the UTF-8 characters but instead translates `Pamêla&~` into `Pam�&~`. Is there another way that would at least give `Pam�la&~`? Why isn't the ascii character ê used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2
       (
          utl_raw.convert
          (
             utl_raw.cast_to_raw(first_name),
             'AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII',   -- To character set.
             'AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8'        -- From Character set.
          )
       ) 
from   per_all_people_f
where  employee_number = '212164'
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are casting to RAW and back again. You can use the CONVERT function. The input string can be CHAR,VARCHAR2,CLOB etc. See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620

You only need to specify the destination character set since it takes the database character set as the default source.

Also, in these cases, never trust the resulting string of letters. Use the dump() function to investigate the byte values that make up the string. This way you can determine if the string is made up of the correct values.

Comment: If I don't use the cast to raw I get ORA-O1465: invalid hex number, so I can't take it out.